# Customize an iframe for Wordpress OneAll Social Login Plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, iframe, attributes

I just installed the OneAll Social Login Plugin for my Wordpress blog 
(*https://wordpress.org/plugins/oa-social-login/*).

This plugin allows user to login into my website using their social media account. I picked Facebook, Twitter and Google for my website.

```
<div class="frame" id="social_login_frame">     
        <div id="content">
            <div id="providers" class="providers_unpaginated"><div class="providers_group" id="providers_group_1"><div class="providers_block"><div class="providers_row"><div class="provider" id="provider_facebook"><a class="button" id="button_facebook" href="#" rel="nofollow" title="Login with Facebook" alt="Login with Facebook"><span class="tick"></span></a><div class="name" id="name_facebook">Facebook</div></div><div class="provider" id="provider_google"><a class="button" id="button_google" href="#" rel="nofollow" title="Login with Google" alt="Login with Google"><span class="tick"></span></a><div class="name" id="name_google">Google</div></div><div class="provider" id="provider_twitter"><a class="button" id="button_twitter" href="#" rel="nofollow" title="Login with Twitter" alt="Login with Twitter"><span class="tick"></span></a><div class="name" id="name_twitter">Twitter</div></div></div></div></div></div>         
        </div>  
        <div class="clear"></div>           
        <div class="footer">            

                <div id="branding">
                    <a href="http://www.oneall.com/services/social-login/?utm_source=mywebsite_login_frame&amp;utm_medium=banner&amp;utm_campaign=branding" target="_blank">Powered&nbsp;by <span class="plugin_title">OneAll&nbsp;Social&nbsp;Login</span></a>
                </div>

            <div id="message"></div>
        </div>  
    </div>


.plugin {
margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 20px 0;
background-color: transparent;
font-size: 12px;
color: #333;
font-family: Helvetica, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.plugin #content {
overflow: hidden;
}

.plugin #providers {
float: left;
position: relative;
}

.plugin #providers .providers_group {
float: left;
}

.plugin #providers.providers_unpaginated .providers_group .providers_block {
padding: 0 !important;
}
.plugin #providers .providers_group .providers_block {
overflow: hidden;
clear: both;
padding: 0 20px;
}

plugin #providers .providers_group .providers_block .providers_row {
clear: both;
}
.plugin #providers .providers_group .providers_block {
overflow: hidden;
clear: both;
padding: 0 20px;
}

.plugin #providers .provider {
width: 35px;
}

.plugin #providers .provider {
float: left;
width: 62px;
text-align: center;
padding: 2px 2px 4px;
outline: 0;
}


.plugin #providers .provider #button_facebook {
background-position: -76px -1px;
}


.plugin #providers .provider .button {
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
background-image: url("/img/api/socialize/providers/logo/sprite_35_35.png");
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
z-index: 9998;
outline: 0;
}
```

Which looks like this:

[image: social login]

If I uncheck

> background-image:
>   url("/img/api/socialize/providers/logo/sprite_35_35.png");

in my Chrome Developer Tools, all of the 3 social media icons disappear.

My goal would be to be able to change these icons for custom 160x32 icons stacked one over eachother, remove *Powered by OneAll Social Login* and be able to customize with CSS *Login With*.

Is there any way I can attribute my own CSS class to elements inside an iframe?

Comment: How to display buttons in the .tpl file ? i have tried 
<div id="oneall_social_login"></div>
 and <div id="oneall_social_login_box"></div> as well but no luck i can not see login with facebook button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login to https://app.oneall.com/signin

Go to implementation tab and then select social login wizard.
[image]
Select "use custom theme" from the "Select your theme:" dropdown
[image]

Upload your css file on your own domain and give a path in the custom css field and then you can add your own social icons styles.
[image]

Hope the answer helps.

Comment: I tried this solution but it's not saving the setting, once you refresh the page it's back to normal, is there something i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

PHP code 
If you are using shortcode into theme

```
<div class="hide-pby">
     <?php echo do_shortcode("[oa_social_login]"); ?>
</div>
```

Else If you using on any plugin or others

```
<div class="hide-pby">
    <?php echo do_action('oa_social_login'); ?>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hide-pby {
    position: relative;
}
.hide-pby::before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 25px;
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #f3f4f6;
}
```